# Generate Certificate stuck Java

Tags: java, sockets, certificate, x509

I'm trying to generate a certificate from a socket input stream but it seems to get stuck when I use the method form CertificateFactory. The program keeps running in the console when it should end.

Here is the code:

```
public PublicKey getCertificate() throws IOException, CertificateException
{
    String resp= br.readLine();
    System.out.println(resp);
    CertificateFactory  cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    System.out.println("GOING TO CREATE CERTIFICATE");
    Certificate certificate =  cf.generateCertificate(socket.getInputStream()); //GETS STUCK

    System.out.println("SUCCESS");
    pw.println(RTA+":"+OK);

    return certificate.getPublicKey();
}
```

The console shows no error whatsoever so I don't know what could be wrong, also I know the socket is getting the information since this is part of a larger communication protocol and the previous communications worked

Comment: Why would you want to get a certificate from a socket?

Comment: @EJP  I'm simulating a client and a server, they comunicate through a socket  so here I'm triying to get the server's certificate so I can continue with the client protocol

Comment: In other words you're reimplementing the SSL handshake? Don't. It's already done. There's a lot more to it than just tranmitting certificates around if you want it to be properly secure.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're connected to either isn't sending a complete binary certificate or isn't closing the socket.